# crontab didn't run on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ubuntu-14.04

- I had a problem about `set crontab` Ubuntu 14.04 on DigitalOcean VPS.
- Here are my steps:

  - First, create new crontab: `crontab -e`
  - Second, i set this command:

This is my crontab which i set it run at 10:26AM everyday:

```
26 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/my_app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake check:user >> log/cron_log.log'
```

- Third, i checked crontab as `crontab -l`
- Finally, i restart crontab as `sudo service cron restart`

But it didn't run anyway (i waited for 10:24 until 10:30), and i copied this command and ran it in my console, it worked very well.

So, i didn't understand why it didn't run same as crontab. Hope everybody can explain or give me some advises. Thank you very much.

EDIT: I tried to use `gem whenever` but it didn't run.

```
set :environment, "production"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever
every :day, at: '10:26am' do
  rake "check:user"
end
```

And i updated my crontab use whenever as `whenever -w`
But it don't work.

Update:
@Coderhs: I tried run this command `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab RAILS_ENV=production`, but it didn't work :(.

This is list my crontab when i use command `crontab -l`:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: RAILS_ENV=production
PATH=/var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=""

26 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/my_app/releases/20150710024713 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake user:check --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: RAILS_ENV=production
```

It still didn't run.

UPDATE: 
The problem was solved. Because in my local TIME was different with SERVER TIME.
So, i had just set SERVER TIME same as my LOCAL TIME. Thank you everybody supported me.

Comment: when you create your crontab just make sure you're admin/su. if that didn't work try getting rid of those single ticks. Don't think you need them around your command

Comment: @FirebladeDan Yes, i used `root` permission. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Like previously mentioned, I would use whenever gem.

Make sure you run whenever -w again after each capistrano deploy so its looking for the correct release directory.

Make sure you run whenever -w as the same user that your application is running as.  Don't use root unless your app is running as root, which it shouldn't be.

Also, you should have your log dir set as a shared directory in Capistrano deploy config.  Something like this in config/deploy.rb :

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'pids', 'public/uploads', 'public/temp')
```

Also run the 'date' command in your terminal and see what the time there is.  It might not be your local time, so the cron could work but at a totally different time than when you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably because the user which runs the cron, can't access the ruby command 'bundle'. You will have to use the full bath to the bundle executable file in the crontab.

The better solution for this problem would be to use the whenever gem https://github.com/javan/whenever

It would manage all the stuff related to crontab, to avoid issues like this.

schedule.rb for whenever

```
set :environment, "production"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']

     # Learn more: github.com/javan/whenever
every :day, at: '10:26am' do
  rake "check:user"
end
```

don't forget to run.

```
bundle exec whenever --update-crontab RAILS_ENV=production
```

after you set the shedule.rb

Comment: I tried to use `gem whenever`, but it didn't run.
This is my code:
set :environment, "production"

set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever
every :day, at: '10:26am' do
  rake "check:user"
end

Comment: @KhanhPham, I have updated my answer a bit. Can you try that and let me know if this runs. If its still not running can you paste the output of `cront_error_log.log`

Comment: After i ran your command, i checked in my log folder and It don't create any log file.

Comment: You added the env `:PATH`, and env `:GEM_PATH` to the `schedule.rb`

Comment: Yes, i added env: `:PATH` and env `:GEM_PATH` to the schedule.rb. But it still didn't work.